# How to change numbers to letters

Tags: mysql

How do I do then following. There are no spaces or dashes in the card_number column

A column that displays the last four digits of the card_number column in this format: XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-1234. In other words, use Xs for the first 12 digits of the card number and actual numbers for the last four digits of the number.

Comment: If you're storing payment card numbers in your database, you're almost certainly in breach of [PCI DSS](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/security_standards/).

Answer (score 2):

```
select 'XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-' + substring(card_number, 16) as masked_card_number
from your_table
```

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/21336)

Answer (score 2):

With the help of substring and concat function you can do that

```
SELECT CONCAT('XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-', SUBSTRING(card_number, -4) AS masked_cc 
FROM table;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. How do you get the last four digits to show in the same column as the X's for example XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-1234

Comment: Thank You I figured it out with the help of your codeCONCAT('XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-',(SUBSTRING(card_number, -4))) AS last_4_digits